# ASP.NET error: More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am building an ASP.NET MVC application, and when add In the Package Manager Console (PMC), enter the following commands:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

I got this error:

> More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.

This is my code:

Comment: Hi @A A, This error means there are several classes that have been inherited from DbContext class.  So add migration with:`Add-Migration InitialCreate -context MvcWatchesContext `.

Answer (score 3):

> More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the
> '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context'
> parameter for dotnet commands.

This error means there are several classes that have been inherited from DbContext class. So add migration with:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -context MvcWatchesContext.
```

Answer (score 0):

PM> Add-Migration AdditionalFields
More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.